# Generic Type Constraint where class implements an abstract class

Tags: c#, generics, abstract-class

I have an `Generic Abstract Class` with some properties like `Id`, `Name`, `Status`, this class inherits several catalogs.
My question is whether it is possible to create a method with a restriction for the catalogs that implement the Abstract Class.

I give some examples so that they understand what I want to do:

```
public abstract class AbsCatalog<T>
{
    public T Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; }
}
```

These are the classes that implement the `abstract class`

```
public class Agent : AbsCatalog<string>
{
    public string Office { get; set; }
    public Estado Estado { get; set; }
}

public class Models : AbsCatalog<int>
{
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

The method I want to implement is the following:

```
List<Agent> Agents = service.GetAgents();
string AgentsDescription = GetDescription<Agent>(Agents);

List<Model> Models = service.GetModels();
string ModelsDescription = GetDescription<Model>(Models);

private string GetDescription<T>(List<T> list) where T : AbsCatalog<T>
{
    string description = string.Empty;

    if (list.Exists(x => x.Id.ToString() == "0"))
        description = "";
    else
        description = string.Join(", ", list.Where(x => x.Status).Select(x => x.Name).ToArray());

    return description;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the only way is to use two generic type parameters here, for example:

```
private string GetDescription<T, U>(List<T> list) where T : AbsCatalog<U>
{
    //snip   
}
```

And then call it like this:

```
string AgentsDescription = GetDescription<Agent, string>(Agents);
```

Comment: But in the validation, it marks an error:
`if (list.Exists(x => x.Id.ToString() == "0"))`
Because now Id is of Type U

Comment: That can't be an error because everything inherits from `object` which has `ToString` on it. Also, you shouldn't be checking against `== "0"`, instead consider `default(U)` or pass in a default value to the method.